# Evaluating a limit without using Lhopitals or series, in other words, just from first principles

Tags: calculus

The limit is

$$ \lim_{ x \to 0 } \frac{ 1 - e^{-x} }{\sin x } $$

### Thoughts:

I multiply by $\frac{x}{x}$ so that we have

$$ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x}{\sin x} \cdot \frac{1-e^{-x}}{x} $$

So, since $\lim \frac{x}{\sin x } = 1$, then we can evaluate instead

$$ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1- e^{-x}}{x} $$

but, is there a way to evaluate this limit in an elementary way? I tried many tricks to no avail.

with lhopitals we know very easily the answer is $\boxed{1}$, but I was wondering of an elementary way.

Comment: Do you know the *definition* of the derivative?

Comment: without using that

Comment: `since lim x/sinx = 1` How have you established that, without l'Hopital, series, or derivatives?

Comment: squeeze rule and geometry

Comment: But how is $e$ defined, after all? Among all exponential functions $a^x$, isn't $e^x$ distinguished by the fact that it's the one that has slope $1$ at $x=0$? We don't know what you know from your course.  I agree that we can do the derivative of $\sin$ by geometry/trigonometry and squeeze.

Comment: @JimmySabater That works, but assumes you know a few other things about $\,\sin\,$. If you knew, for example, that $\,e^x\,$ is convex and tangent to $\,y=x+1\,$, then you could use that for a proof. But I guess the question is *what* do you know about $\,e^x\,$, and are allowed to use here.

Comment: So how do your text [suppose there is one] derive the derivative of $\mathrm e^x$? The process would give you some hint about doing your problem in an elementary way. Although this might needs the continuity, if that is also not allowed, then things would be trickier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^{-x}-1}{-x}=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{e^{h}-1}{h}=1$$

The first equality is the substitution $-x=h$, and the second equality is (sometimes) taken as the definition of the number $e$.

Comment: I wouldn't say "usually" at all! But in some courses, yes.

Answer (score 1):

As a comment pointed out, your limit is very close to a derivative:

\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1-e^{-x}}{x}&=-\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{e^{-x}-1}{x} \\
&=-\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{e^{-x}-e^{-0}}{x-0} \\
&=-\frac{d}{dx} e^{-x}\Biggr|_{x=0} \\
&=1
\end{align}

Comment: actually, while this is a fine answer, I was wondering if there is a more elementary way to solve it.

Comment: @JimmySabater: Not really.  In some textbooks, $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^x-1}{x} =1$ is the definition of $e$.

Comment: Yeah, @MatthewLeingang, just the point I raised in comments above.

Answer (score 1):

May this be useful someday, 
$$\lim_{x\to0} \frac{1- e^{-x}}{x}=\lim_{x\to0}\int_0^1e^{-tx}\ dt=\int_0^1 \lim_{x\to0}e^{-tx}\ dt=1$$